# VBA Excel: Insert an extract of a spreadsheet into an Outlook email

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I want to be able to run a macro in Excel that copies specific areas of my excel spreadsheet, opens a new email, and pastes the areas in. So far I have got the following code:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
'Macro2 Macro
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim TempFilePath As String
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Dim rng As Range
'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:E200").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With objMail

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$P$197").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="10"
    Range("B171:F184,I171:J184").Select
    Range("I171").Activate
    Range("B171:F184,I171:J184,M171:N184").Select
    Range("M171").Activate
    Selection.Copy


    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display
End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

This code almost does what I want, it copies filters on criteria 10 in column D and copies and pastes this into an email.

But what I want is for the code to go through the filtered cells (could be criteria 1, 2, 3... etc. rather than a hard coded criteria as it is at the minute), and copy & paste specific columns into the email.

For example, I want to filter on Queen in the Band column below and copy & paste the columns C (Full Name) and D (Band) into an email.

```
     A            B              C               D             
 1   First name:  Last name:     Full Name:      Band:
 2   Freddie      Mercury        Freddie Mercury Queen
 3   Brian        May            Brian May       Queen
 4   Kurt         Cobain         Kurt Cobain     Nirvana
 5   Roger        Taylor         Roger Taylor    Queen
 6   Dave         Grohl          Dave Grohl      Nirvana
 7   John         Deacon         John Deacon     Queen
 8   Kris         Novoselic      Kris Novoselic  Nirvana
```

Is there a way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess I am missing something because it cannot be as simple as `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:D200").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` in order to copy only columns C and D as requested, right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't make this clear in the question, but the columns wouldn't necessarily be next to each other, e.g. columns B and D. So I'm not sure if your suggestion would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was change `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:E200").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`
to the range I needed, so `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:E200, I4:J200, M4:N200").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

This was similar to the comment provided by @Ralph but with the different ranges.